# Need advice on code java efficiency

Tags: java, calculator, coding-efficiency

I am new to java programming and I just created a calculator program and it seems to work fine but other programmers seem to use "parsing a lot" in their calculator programs. Just wanted to ask whether I'm taking a wrong approach and might run into problems in the future using this kind of logic.Thanks.

```
class Refresh {

private final String a;
private final String b;
private final String c;
private final String d;
private double x, y;

public Refresh() {
    a = "Enter the first number: ";
    b = "Enter the function; ";
    c = "Enter the second number: ";
    d = "The result is: ";
}

public void types() {
    Scanner typ = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        System.out.println(a);
        x = typ.nextDouble();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please use only numbers!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println(b);
    String func = typ.next();

    try {
        System.out.println(c);
        y = typ.nextDouble();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please use only numbers!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    switch (func) {

        case "+":
            System.out.println(d + (x + y));
            break;

        case "-":
            System.out.println(d + (x - y));
            break;
        case "/":
            if (y == 0) {

                System.out.println("Cannot divide by zero!");
            } else {
                System.out.println(d + (x / y));
            }
            break;
        case "*":
            System.out.println(d + (x * y));
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println(func + " is not valid function");
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Refresh fin = new Refresh();
        fin.types();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what "parsing a lot" means in this question

Comment: Sorry, i meant i see the "parse" method a lot in their programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is fine as a demo or as a step in learning Java, but you probably would not use it as a production program.  The reason is that your code assumes a command line interface (static void main(), Scanner, System.out.println()).

Users are used to graphical solutions nowadays.  They expect the input and output to be given in a graphical front end and the calculations should be done in separate logic.

In this view, I would restructure your program in 3 parts:

- A back end class which does the calculations (the Calculator class in the following sample code)
- A front end class (called SimpleFrontEnd below) which builds on your code, but could later be replaced with e.g. a web interface
- Data objects to communicate between back end and front end (the Calculation class below to send info from the front end to the back end)

Having these 3 parts, you can modify them independently of each other.  You could decide that in the front end you only enter a single String, which is then parsed before being sent to the back end.

I would probably NOT use a single String in the front end that needs to be parsed, but a JSON object that maps directly to the Calculation class below, for the following reason: the front end can easily modify the operands and operator of the JSON object independently of each other, whereas modifying a string that has to be parsed is more complex.

Here is sample code that separates front end from back end:

```
public class Calculation {
    private double leftOperand;
    private String operator;
    private double rightOperand;

    public double getLeftOperand() {
        return leftOperand;
    }

    public void setLeftOperand(double leftOperand) {
        this.leftOperand = leftOperand;
    }

    public String getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }

    public void setOperator(String operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    public double getRightOperand() {
        return rightOperand;
    }

    public void setRightOperand(double rightOperand) {
        this.rightOperand = rightOperand;
    }
}

public class Calculator {
    public double calculate(Calculation calculation) {
        switch (calculation.getOperator()) {
            case "+":
                return calculation.getLeftOperand() + calculation.getRightOperand();
            case "-":
                return calculation.getLeftOperand() - calculation.getRightOperand();
            case "/":
                if (calculation.getRightOperand() == 0) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot divide by zero!");
                }
                return calculation.getLeftOperand() / calculation.getRightOperand();
            case "*":
                return calculation.getLeftOperand() * calculation.getRightOperand();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("%s is not valid function", calculation.getOperator()));
        }
    }
}

public class SimpleFrontEnd {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //1. input, could be later replaced with a front end
            Scanner typ = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
            double x = typ.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the function: ");
            String func = typ.next();
            System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
            double y = typ.nextDouble();

            //2. store input in an data object that will be sent to the back end (later on, a web interface could send this as a JSON)
            Calculation calculation = new Calculation();
            calculation.setLeftOperand(x);
            calculation.setOperator(func);
            calculation.setRightOperand(y);

            //3. retrieve the result from the back end
            Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
            try {
                double result = calculator.calculate(calculation);
                System.out.println(String.format("The result is: %f", result));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please use only numbers!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn!! I will forever respect you for this. I could learn so much from this , am gonna spend the next coming days just studying this code. Thank you so much!

Comment: It is a pleasure if I can help, though this is a simple example and I cannot give all answers in this post, though I can tell you what are from my experience the most important ones. When I started my career as a software engineer about 10 years ago, I was given the advice that software should have "loose coupling and high cohesion". I think that is the single most important law in software design. As for getting experience, I think the 2 most important ways are practice and reading. In practice, you see what others are doing and through reading you learn from smart people. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Parsing just means to scan a group of characters and then separate them into their own structures (tokenize them).

`String aStr = "10";`

The variable `aStr` would be of type `String`. You could then parse the string.

`int aInt = Integer.parseInt(aStr);`

Comment: Thanks for that, so i don't really need it in my code above right?

Comment: It is fine because you are calling `type.nextDouble()` which returns a double instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information, Java has a built in calculator library.

```
ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String result = "100/10";
System.out.println(scriptEngine.eval(result));
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, i will be more happy if you would have just answered the question and then gave a suggestion. Because I feel this answer is no where close to the OP question. As he is new to Java, introducing new items gets overwhelming.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this is actually very basic example. And honestly you did a great job. and even better at asking this question at this time. Usually people ignore efficiency during the learning process and get too late.

Why do they do parsing?

If you donot know about the below, then you should probably try [reading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) more on it.

Scanner reads all the key inputs from users. Lets take example

Enter a number> `12`

Scanner will hold `12\n`

Now you see that? scanner is holding on to just number it is actually hold on to a string. which contains `12` and `\n`

When you ask scanner `nextDouble` it will just give you `12`.

But then it is still holding on to that `\n` so the next string input, the string `\n` will be assigned.

By parsing, you will ignore this issue. And you will have better control over user input.

Comment: Thanks a million for taking the time to answer Smit, now am getting it

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation. Happy to help. :) @OfentseProsperNglazi

Comment: it seems you understood "parsing" differently than I did.  If it is related to the Scanner your answer is relevant.

Comment: I habe tried to stick to the OP.question not adding any extra NEW element to confuse him. As he is new to JAVA i really dont him to be scratching his head.